# How to make data loading from server before view is drawing in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I have a problem with data loading and view drawing in swift. My app is getting data from the server, but before I get data the table view is loading, that's why I need to reload it few times, this looks strange for me as a new developer, I do not think this should work that way. So, my question is how to load data from the server before the view is loaded. Because in my way it is easy to crash the app, just tapping before the data loaded. I tried DispatchQeue in different ways, but do not get how to solve this problem.

Here is the code on how I get data from the server and update my table view.

```
import Foundation

typealias OnApiSuccesPeople = (people) -> Void
typealias OnApiError = (String) -> Void
typealias OnApiSuccesPlanet = (planet) -> Void

struct ApiService {
    static let shared = ApiService()
    
    let URL_BASE = "https://swapi.dev/api"
    let URL_PEOPLE = "/people"
    let URL_PEOPLE_PAGE_NUMBERFROMCYCLE = "/?page="
    let URL_PLANETS = "/planets"
    
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    
    func getResultsFromURL(onSuccess: @escaping OnApiSuccesPeople, onError: @escaping OnApiError, urlStringType: String) {

        let url = URL(string: "\(urlStringType)")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET" // GET, PUT, POST, DELETE for some different api
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                if let error = error {
                    onError(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }

                guard let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                    onError("Invalid data or response")
                    return
                }

                do{
                    if response.statusCode == 200 {
                        
                        let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(people.self, from: data)
                        onSuccess(results)
                    } else {
                        let err = try JSONDecoder().decode(APIError.self, from: data)
                        print("Code is \(response.statusCode)")
                        onError(err.detail)
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    onError(error.localizedDescription)
                }

            }
        }
        task.resume()

        }
```

```
import UIKit

class MainVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    
    @IBOutlet weak var charNameTable: UITableView!
    
    
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        getResults()
        getPlanets()

        charNameTable.delegate = self
        charNameTable.dataSource = self
        
    }
    
    
    func getResults() {
        ApiService.shared.getResultsFromURL(onSuccess: { (people) in
            results.append(contentsOf: people.results)
            results.sort {$0.name < $1.name}
            self.charNameTable.reloadData()
        }, onError: { (error) in
            debugPrint(error)
        }, urlStringType: "\(ApiService.shared.URL_BASE)\(ApiService.shared.URL_PEOPLE)")
        
        for i in 2...9 {
            ApiService.shared.getResultsFromURL(onSuccess: { (people) in
                results.append(contentsOf: people.results)
                results.sort {$0.name < $1.name}
                self.charNameTable.reloadData()
            }, onError: { (error) in
                debugPrint(error)
            }, urlStringType: "\(ApiService.shared.URL_BASE)\(ApiService.shared.URL_PEOPLE)\(ApiService.shared.URL_PEOPLE_PAGE_NUMBERFROMCYCLE)\(i)")
        }

    }
    
    func getPlanets() {
            for i in 1...60 {
                ApiService.shared.getPlanetsFromURL(onSuccess: { (planet) in
                    resultsPlanets.append(planet)
                }, onError: { (error) in
                    debugPrint(error)
                }, urlStringType: "\(ApiService.shared.URL_BASE)\(ApiService.shared.URL_PLANETS)/\(i)")
            }
            
    }
    

    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return results.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CharacterCell") as? CharacterCell {
            cell.updatecell(resuls: results[indexPath.row])
            return cell
        }
        
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let detail = results[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "DetailedVC", sender: detail)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        initDetailedResults()
        
        
        if let detailedVC = segue.destination as? DetailedVC {
            detailedVC.initDetailedResultsForScreen(result: sender as! result)
            
        }
    }
    

}
```

Comment: You should be loading the data on a separate async queue. You can keep reloading the table in intervals while the data is being loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Combine framework to Publish and Subscribe

```
import Combine 

class ApiService: ObservableObject {

    @Published var items = Array<people>()

    // ...

    items = try JSONDecoder().decode(people.self, from: data)

    // ...

    

}
```

Then you can listen for items in your controller and update UITableView

```
import Combine

class MainVC: UIViewController {

    // ....
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    // ...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        getResults()
        getPlanets()

        charNameTable.delegate = self
        charNameTable.dataSource = self

        ApiService.shared.$items
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] people in
                self?.results = people
                self?.charNameTable.reloadData()
                
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
     
    

}
```

Comment: is it possible to this only with DispatchQueue.main.async?

Comment: No, you can receive on any thread but for this example when you update UI using reloadData() it's better